# how to replace \n message.properties in html

Tags: properties, thymeleaf

I'm doing multilingual work using message.properties.

In a simple html page, the text content is shown through the message.properties code.

But when the newline \ n tag is not working in the html page.

how to replace \n message properties in html ?

ex)

//messages_en.properties file

index.main=We make the software 2.0 world \n where everyone smiles.

// in html

```html
 <p th:text="#{index.main}"></p>
```

i want to

"We make the software 2.0 world

where everyone smiles."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to replace `\n` with `<br/>` and use `th:utext` attribute instead `th:text` in order to render message as HTML.

Insead of `<br/>` tag you can use ASCII code `&#10;` and wrap the message with `<pre>` HTML tag.

Comment: I solved it and tried to reply. Thank you for answering it first. 
I fixed it with utext by writing <br/> tags in the properties file. Thank you.

Comment: First paragraph is copied from another answer without understanding the context. `&#10;` works in markup but not in properties file.

Comment: You are actually right. Thymeleaf renders `&#10;`as text. But you can actually use ASCII tag in `<pre>` HTML tag and also in this case you need to use `th:utext` attribute in Thymeleaf. I will modify my answer.